# MySQL Foreign Key own table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table with it's own null foreign key. This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `modules_submodules` (
    `submodule_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `submodule_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `submodule_idparent` INT  NULL,
    `submodule_icon` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`submodule_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `modules_submodule_id_UNIQUE` (`submodule_id` ASC),
    INDEX `modules_submodules_to_submodules_idx` (`submodule_idparent` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `submodules_to_submodules` FOREIGN KEY (`submodule_idparent`)
        REFERENCES `submodules` (`submodule_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint    0.078 sec

What's causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Fixed typos, Touched up grammar. Remember to include an actual question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistyped name of the reference table:

```
REFERENCES `submodules` (`submodule_id`)
```

instead of

```
REFERENCES `modules_submodules` (`submodule_id`)
```

Complete query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `modules_submodules` (
    `submodule_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `submodule_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `submodule_idparent` INT  NULL,
    `submodule_icon` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`submodule_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `modules_submodule_id_UNIQUE` (`submodule_id` ASC),
    INDEX `modules_submodules_to_submodules_idx` (`submodule_idparent` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `submodules_to_submodules` FOREIGN KEY (`submodule_idparent`)
        REFERENCES `modules_submodules` (`submodule_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```